# Dynamic values in json parsing with GWT

Tags: java, json, gwt

I have a json response like this

```
{  
   "columns":[  
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
   ],
   "data":[{  
      "a":"some value",
      "b":"some value",
      "c":"some value"
   },
   {  
      "a":"some value 2",
      "b":"some value 2",
      "c":"some value 2"
   }
   ]
}
```

Now here whatever values columns have the same values are used as keys in data object. I have to parse this json in GWT client side. As far as I know JSNI requires fixed json objects. Is there any way to parse this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with it here's how I did it.

```
public final native JsArray<Columns> getColumns() /*-{ return this.columns; }-*/;
public final native JsArray<Data> getData() /*-{ return this.data; }-*/;

public static class Data extends JavaScriptObject {
    protected Data() {}

    public final native String getValue(String key) /*-{ return this[key]; }-*/;
}
public static class Columns extends JavaScriptObject {
    protected Columns() {}
    public final native String getValue() /*-{ return this; }-*/;
}
```